# Unittesting code in another python file

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-import

Suppose you have a python script with the following function and saved as sum.py

```
def sum(x, y):
     return x + y
```

how do you call this script from another script and unittest it?

Answer (score 2):

you put your `sum.py` file which contains the code you mentioned, and in your other script file you call it with `import` like this example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sum
print sum.sum(2,4)
```

to get more information regard this, look [here](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html)

hope this helps.

Comment: please edit your original post, code from a comment is not readable.

Comment: You are amazing! Thanks. I was doing the wrong thing. I was doing this: import sum print sum(2, 1) instead of what you posted. My goal was to unit test this function, but I did not know how to call it